# How to find the joint histogram of a volume data?

Tags: image, histograms

This question is in reference to [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.92.502&rep=rep1&type=pdf) paper. In Fig. 1b, the joint histogram of data value and gradient magnitude is plotted. What I understand is that the values in the plot represent the frequencies of voxels having the corresponding data value and gradient. However, I am confused how to implement this in Mathematica. Below is what I have tried so far:

```
img = ImageRotate[Import["ChapelHillCThead.tif", "Image3D"], {Pi, {1, 0, 0}}];
data = ImageData[img];
imggrad = GradientFilter[img, 1];
grad = ImageData[imggrad];
dataf = Flatten@data;
gradf = Flatten@grad;
nd = BinCounts[dataf, {0, 1, 1/255}];
ng = BinCounts[gradf, {0, 1, 1/255}];
(* This is to calculate the joint histogram *)
jh = Table[Min[nd[[i]], ng[[j]]], {i, 1, 255}, {j, 1, 255}];
```

I know this cannot give me the desired result. However, I don't find any alternative way apart from checking the data value and gradient for each voxel and count them.

How can I get the desired result in a fast and efficient way?

[The Chapel Hill CT dataset can be found [here](http://www9.informatik.uni-erlangen.de/External/vollib/)]

Comment: I find .pvn files in the link you mention, how did you convert it to .tif? Can you upload a directly importable file?

Comment: Also have a look at the `Histogram` function

Comment: @Ruud3.1415 Please check this link[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sUjrMR7V76fOK3uMv5_Cc3bkNCZPmEra/view?usp=sharing] for the file.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. How does `ImageHistogram[Import["ChapelHillCThead.tif", "Image3D"]]` work for you?

Comment: @Ruud3.1415 It works fine. Do you want the screenshot?

Comment: @Ruud3.1415 emailed the histogram.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68549/discussion-between-ruud3-1415-and-majis).

Answer (score 2):

This is more of an extended comment than an answer.

Because there are around 7.4 million observations, taking a large random sample can make things simpler.

```
(* Take a random sample of the 7.4 million observations *)
d = Transpose[{dataf, gradf}];
r = RandomSample[d, 100000];

(* Plot the values of the random sample *)
ListPlot[r]
```

[image: Plot of random sample of data]

To obtain a smooth version of a histogram you can use the `SmoothKernelDistribution` function:

```
skd = SmoothKernelDistribution[r];
ContourPlot[PDF[skd, {x, y}], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 0.12},
 PlotRange -> All, Contours -> 20, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: SmoothKernelDistribution contour plot]

There's also the `Histogram3D` function:

```
Histogram3D[r, Automatic, "PDF"]
```

[image: 3D histogram]

But in all of these figures, I don't see any relationship for the two variables similar to what is displayed in the referenced article.